# Trouble updating database with Time values

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, orm

I have an MVC app and I'm having trouble updating Time values in the database.  When I submit the form, i have no trouble saving a Time value to the database the first time, it's only when I perform an edit to change the Time value in the database that I get the error "The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the equal operator."  All other data type fields update just fine.  I'm using SQL Management Server 2008.  The column in the database is of datatype `time(2)`.  We are using ORM so in the model, the property is a `DateTime` object.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

In the form:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m => m.TimeIn)
                    .Format("hh:mm:ss tt")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { readOnly = "readOnly" })
                )
```

My View Model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Time In")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm:ss tt}")]
    public DateTime TimeIn { get; set; }
```

And inside my controller:

```
    public ActionResult EditQuote(QuoteViewModel _quote)
    {
         using (var dbContext = new EntitiesModel())
         {
             var _existingQuote //Get entry in database.
             _existingQuote.TimeIn = _quote.TimeIn;
             dbContext.SaveChanges();
         }         
    }
```

Can anyone see what the problem is here?  Thanks in advance, Shaun

Comment: probably your Model Datatype should be TimeSpan rather than datetime. Give a try in that way.

Comment: Hello ramiramilu,  I tried that approach.  Unfortunately the mvc project is synced with the database through Telerik ORM Open Access and that creates the db model as a DateTime object.  When I changed the property in the view model to a time span I get a compilaton error about incompatible taps.